# what´s the difference between I don´t mind and I don´t care

Tags: differences

I am looking for the difference meaning between 'I don´t care' and 'I don´t mind'

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

They are almost synonymous, and are sometimes used that way, but they have slightly different connotations.

- I don't care = I'm apathetic or it doesn't matter to me
- I don't mind = I care, but I don't object

Comment: It's actually very difficult to think of a context where you'd use non-negated "mind" to mean *be bothered by*. Unless it's negated, it usually means *pay attention to [the step, your manners, what you say, etc.]*

Comment: @Fumble Except in questions and replies. A:“Do you mind if I smoke?” – B: “No, I don't mind.” C: “Well, _I_ mind, so please don't.”

Answer (score 0):

**[I don't care](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/I+don%27t+mind)** means 'It doesn't matter to me'.

> Mary: Can I take these papers away?
>
> Tom: I don't care

However **I don't mind** means that 'we are allowing it to happen'.